# Function to avoid double click not working with input submit on chrome only

Tags: jquery

This code is to avoid double clicks on form submit by disabling the button for few second with setTimeout

It works well on IE & Firefox but the form never submits on Chrome

```
<input type="submit" id="button" class="button" onclick="foo(this);" name="submit_forgot" value="Submit" />
```

and here is the function:

```
  function foo(obj) {
    obj.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        obj.disabled = false;
    }, 2000);
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `data` to support multiple buttons, if need be.

```js
$("#button").click(function () {
  if ($(this).data("disable")) {
    return false;
  }
  $(this).data("disable", true);
  
  clearInterval($(this).data("interval"));
  
  $(this).data("interval", setInterval(function () {
    $(this).data("disable", false);
  }.bind(this), 2000));
  
  console.log("called");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="button" class="button" name="submit_forgot" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working well! For other newby like me I had to wrap it inside $(document).ready(function() {}.